Pandas: KeyError using df.loc with condition
Using the following program which selects the rows with numbers included in 'Num' in a DataFrame.
import pandas as pd 
data = {'Num': [[1,2,100], [10,20,30], [1,2,30],[1,2,200],[4,0,9]],'Id':range(5)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
numbers = [1,2]
filtered_df = df.loc[all(n in df['Num'] for n in numbers)]
print(filtered_df)

I have the following error:

raise KeyError(KeyError: 'True: boolean label can not be used without a boolean index'


I do not understand the reason for this error because if I change filtered_df by:
filtered_df = df.loc[df['Num'].apply(lambda c : all(n in c for n in numbers))]

The program works well. Can you please explain the error and how to correct the first program?

The all function aggregates several boolean values into a single value. In your example, the input you are using in your first problem to get the rows in which your condition is true is:
all(n in df['Num'] for n in numbers)
> True

But you cannot get a dataframe index for a boolean.
In your second example, the lambda function is applied to each row, as per the definition of DataFrame.apply(...).

all(n in df['Num'] for n in numbers) is going to check that all numbers in numbers are in the index of df['Num'] and output a single True. Then this tries to index with that, being equivalent df.loc[True], which doesn't make sense since there is not True in your index.
The correct loc approach would be:
df.loc[[all(n in lst for n in numbers) for lst in df['Num']]]

Which is equivalent to:
df.loc[[True, False, True, True, False]]


Thank you for the explanation. It is effectively the origin of the error
